# Lucene Search Returns no results when the file contents are saved

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, lucene

I am trying to develop a log querying system using apache lucene. I have developed a demo  code to index two files and then search for the query string.

The first file contains the data
maclean

the second file contains the data 
pinto

Bellow is the code that I have used for indexing

```
 fis = new FileInputStream(file);
  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  String strLine;
  Document doc = new Document();

  Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new TextField("contents", new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8"))));

    doc.add(new StoredField("filename", file.getCanonicalPath()));

    if (indexWriter.getConfig().getOpenMode() == OpenMode.CREATE) {

       System.out.println("adding " + file);
      indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
   } else {

        System.out.println("updating " + file);
        indexWriter.updateDocument(new Term("path", file.getPath()), doc);
      }
```

If i use this code then i get the proffer result. But in display i can show only the file name since i have stored the only the file name.

So i modified the code and stored the file contents as well using this code

```
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        if (file.isHidden() || file.isDirectory() || !file.canRead() || !file.exists()) {
            return;
        }
        if (suffix!=null && !file.getName().endsWith(suffix)) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Indexing file " + file.getCanonicalPath());

        try {
          fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
          System.out.println("File Not Found"+fnfe);

       }
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
      String strLine;   
      String Data="";
     while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
         {
            Data=Data+strLine;
         }

        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new TextField("contents", Data, Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new StoredField("filename", file.getCanonicalPath()));

        if (indexWriter.getConfig().getOpenMode() == OpenMode.CREATE) {

           System.out.println("adding " + file);
          indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
       } else {

            System.out.println("updating " + file);
            indexWriter.updateDocument(new Term("path", file.getPath()), doc);
          }
```

According to my understanding i should get the number of results as 1. and It should show the file name and content of the file containing maclean

But instead i get the result as

-----------------------Results--------------------------

0 total matching documents
Found 0

Is there anything wrong that i am doing in the code or there is a logical explanation to this? Why does the first code works and second doesn't work?

Search query Code

```
 try
   {
    Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(indexDir);
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_41);

    QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_41, "contents", analyzer);
    Query query = parser.parse(queryStr);
    System.out.println("Searching for: " + query.toString("contents"));
    TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, maxHits);

    ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;
    int numTotalHits = results.totalHits;

    System.out.println("\n\n\n-----------------------Results--------------------------\n\n\n");
   System.out.println(numTotalHits + " total matching documents");


    for (int i = 0; i < numTotalHits; i++) {
        int docId = hits[i].doc;
        Document d = searcher.doc(docId);

                   System.out.println(i+":File name is: "+d.get("filename"));
                   System.out.println(i+":File content is: "+d.get("contents"));



    }
    System.out.println("Found " + numTotalHits);
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    System.out.println("Exception Was caused in SimpleSearcher");
    e.printStackTrace();

   }
```

Comment: Did you close/commit the IndexWriter before searching?

Comment: no i have not  closed the IndexWriter

Comment: Could you post your search query code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use StoredField instead of TextField

doc.add(new StoredField("Data",Line));

When you use Text Field the string gets tokenized and as a result you will not be able to search for the same. Stored Field stores the entire string without tokenizing it.

Comment: Your answer seems to indicate that a StoredField will allow searching on the field.  A StoredField is not indexed, and so can not be searched at all.  If you were to want to index the entire String as a single token, you would want to use [StringField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html), or similar.  Also, Tokenizing only applies to how a field is indexed, not how it is stored.

Answer (score 1):

I think your exact problem, is that by the time you get to creating a BufferedReader for the indexed field, you have already read the whole file, and the stream is at the end of the file, with nothing further to read.  You should be able to fix that with a call to `fis.reset();`

However, you should not do that.  Don't store the same data in two separate fields, one for indexing and one for storage.  Instead, set the same field to both store and index the data.  [TextField has a ctor](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/TextField.html#TextField%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.apache.lucene.document.Field.Store%29) that allows you to store the data as well as index, something like:

```
doc.add(new TextField("contents", Data, Field.Store.YES));
```

Comment: Nice observation about the stream @femtoRgon. But that (reading the complete file before creating `BufferedReader` for indexed field) is happening in the first code  (one posted on top) as well and that code, as Maclean says, is getting proper results. Or am I missing something..

Comment: @Kshitij The first example was indexing the contents correctly, I believe, but not storing them.  If they aren't stored, they can not be retrieved.

Comment: @MacleanPinto Try printing Data before you write it to the index.  It might be that the data you are building doesn't look quite like you think it does.  It strikes me that concatenating lines fetched with `readLine()` will lose the new lines, joining words into one token that should be separate, as well as messing up the stored value.  Fixing that issue might be as simple as changing to `Data=Data+"\n"+strLine;`  [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) is a very handy tool for debugging that sort of thing.

Comment: @femtoRgon I was using lucene 4.1. luke doesn't support 4.1 Anyways I have got it working. I used the textfield for indexing just like use suggested. and stored the string as a storefield to store the data. BUt i do agree that this doc.add(new TextField("contents", Data, Field.Store.YES)); should have worked. So i will accept it anyways

Answer (score 0):

I think there could be two problems with your code.

First, I notice that you did not user near-real-time search and did not commit the writer before reading as well. Lucene's IndexReader takes a snapshot of the index, either the committed version when NRT is not used or both committed and uncommitted version when NRT is used. That could be the reason that your IndexReader fails to see the change. As it seems you require concurrent reading and writing, I recommend you use NRT search (`IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(indexWriter);`)

The second problem could be that, as @femtoRgon said, the data you stored may not what you expect. I notice that, when you append the content of your file for storage, you seem to lose EOL characters. I suggest you use Luke to check your index http://www.getopt.org/luke/

Answer (score 0):

This works in Lucene 4.5: doc.add(new TextField("Data", Data, Field.Store.YES));